# Ordinary Differential Equation Solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can't for the life of me figure out how to solve this ODE I found. It doesn't seem complicated and should have a solution but I have tried most online ODE solvers but they always return a "cannot compute solution". I know this is a dumb place to ask but I'm gonna have a hard time sleeping if I can't figure it out. It doesn't seem to be separable either.

The problem is:

$$2yy'= x-y+y^3$$

Even just an answer would be helpful,
Cheers.

Comment: I decided to delete my answer because I couldn't find the correct integrating factor. I will try to find another way to solve it :(

Comment: From where did you get this ODE?

Answer (score 1):

Consider first the equation
$$2yy'= -y+y^3$$ Switch variables to make
$$2\frac y{x'}=-y+y^3 \implies x'=\frac{2}{y^2-1}\implies x+C=\log \left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)$$ that is to say
$$y=\frac{1-K e^x}{1+K e^x}$$ Now, trying the variation of parameters, this would give $\color{red}{\text{No hope}}$